# Is there a way to sort 500 test cases in test run (KIWI TCMS)

Tags: kiwi-tcms

We have test runs with several hundred test cases. We can sort them manually but it is very inconvenient and time consuming. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what exactly you want to sort?

You can achieve some things via GUI but currently the most powerful way to manipulate (bulk edit) test cases is via the [Kiwi TCMS API](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The order in TR comes from the order inside TestPlan where you can reorder the test cases (top-right corner). If you need something in particular then you have to describe it.

Comment: I just want them to be ordered by ID. They are not ordered  in test plan and to reorder them manually will take significant time. I wasn’t able to find a way to reorder them other than drag and drop in test plan.

Comment: Open test plan. Click on ID column to have them sorted by ID. Click on Re-order cases. Click Done Sorting.